# How to pass value with ionChange?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vue-component

I am trying to pass a few values with ionChange, index and the 0 are passed correctly but value becomes undefined. Is there any way to pass the value?

```html
<ion-select placeholder="Select One" @ionChange="catChange(value, Index,0)" v-model="trip.shelfSetups[Index].categoriesOnShelf[0].categoryId">
    <ion-select-option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.id" v-bind:key="category.id">{{ category.name }}
</ion-select-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution in case anybody runs into the same problem, replace value with $event.

```html
<ion-select placeholder="Select One" @ionChange="catChange($event, Index,0)" v-model="trip.shelfSetups[Index].categoriesOnShelf[0].categoryId">
        <ion-select-option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.id" v-bind:key="category.id">{{ category.name }}
</ion-select-option>
```

and then get the value.detail.val to get the value.